# Convert JSONObject to String where values are 0.0

Tags: java, json

I came across the issue when I have the following JSONObject (org.json):

```
{
"float1": 0.0,
"float2": 0.1
}
```

When I call toString method on the object I get the string:

```
{"float1": 0,"float2": 0.1}
```

so 0.0 is converted to 0, which causes many problems for me. Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: It shouldn't cause you problems. The numbers 0 and 0.0 are the same. What IS the problem? What is the relevant code?

Comment: Let's imagine two jsons one which is let's say pattern and the second one which is a result of some processing. My testing tool (JSON comparator) takes two JSON strings which are different "0.0".equals("0") is False

Comment: The natural follow on is going to be why are you comparing strings instead of comparing the values?

Comment: @user3450486 isn't it easier to change the JSON comparator's method to check if the argument is equals to "0" ?

Comment: in JSON, `{a: 1, b: 2}` is the equivalent to `{b: 2, a: 1}` for example. Comparing strings is not what you should do. What you should do is that the JSON are semantically equivalent: they have the same keys, with equal values. Parse the two JSON strings to Maps, and compare that the Maps are equal.

Comment: I change the JSONObject to String because I upload it to an amq. That's the reason why I have to do the conversion. Then I get message from the queue, convert to JSONObject and do my comparison

Comment: Show your code. Tell us what you expect it to do, and what it does instead. You're contradicting yourself. First you say that you're comparing JSON strings, the you says that you're comparing JSONObject instances.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wants. However this solution will force you to use your own class extended from JSONObject and it's only functionality is to override the toString() method of JSONObject, i don't know if it's worth it.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class Test extends JSONObject {
    public Test(String in) throws JSONException {
        super(in);
    }

    public static Test jsonObj = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        jsonObj = new Test("{float1: 0.0, float2: 0.1}");
        System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("{");
        String[] box = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObj);
        for (int i = 0; i < JSONObject.getNames(jsonObj).length; i++) {
            try {
                sb.append(box[i])
                        .append(" ")
                        .append(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.1f",
                                jsonObj.get(box[i])))
                        .append(i != JSONObject.getNames(jsonObj).length - 1 ? ","
                                : "");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        sb.append("}");
        return sb.toString();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try Gson to implement this.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, new DoubleSerializer()).create();
TestBean bean = gson.fromJson(jsonInput, TestBean.class);
String jsonOutput = gson.toJson(bean);
```

DoubleSerializer:

```
    class DoubleSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Double> {
    public JsonElement serialize(Double src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(String.format("%.1f", src));
      }
}
```

TestBean.java:

```
 public class TestBean {
    private Double float1;
    private Double float2;

    public Double getFloat1() {
        return float1;
    }
    public void setFloat1(Double float1) {
        this.float1 = float1;
    }
    public Double getFloat2() {
        return float2;
    }
    public void setFloat2(Double float2) {
        this.float2 = float2;
    }   
}
```

If jsonInput is

```
{
 "float1": 0.0, 
 "float2": 1.31
}
```

The jsonOutput will be:

```
{
   "float1": "0.0",
   "float2": "1.3"
}
```